# how to change all input field values into upper case

Tags: php

I have set of PHP fields.

Before sending the values into a query, I want to change the letters to upper case.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
$cust_name   = "john";
$cust_gender = "male";

lower_upper_conversion($_);
```

so that now john has changed to JOHN, and male has changed to MALE?

After this function is crossed or passed, all variables need to change into upper case.

I do not want normal solution where I have to call for each field:

```
$cust_name   = "john";
$cust_gender = "male";

lower_upper_conversion($cust_name);
lower_upper_conversion($cust_gender);
JOHN , MALE,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$_POST = array_map("strtoupper", $_POST);
```

This will make all values in the POSTed form upper case.

There is no general method to apply a function to all variables in scope. They need to be in an array first.

Comment: I'm giving you the +1 for `array_map` in conjunction with `strtoupper`, however I *wouldn't* suggest using it directly on `$_POST`, instead you ought to place the data in its own array so that you're not contaminating user input.

Comment: something like this let me test it, i am using class object structure, in class, have function called add_my_details, inside this function how to use the array_map, i dont have idea how to call the call back function, i tried something like this, but does't work, got error i tried like array_map("strtoupperf", $_POST); and also i tried    array_map($this->strtoupperf(), $_POST);  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mod_expense::strtoupperf()

Comment: What are the variables you want to make upper case? Properties of the class? Arguments to the `add_my_details` method? You have not provided enough information to help. Nobody said there was a function called `strtoupperf`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

```
$cust_name = "john";
echo strtoupper($cust_name); // Outputs JOHN
```

Comment: He specifically asked for a method where he would not call the function on each separate field.

Comment: this is normal, i don't look normal holder,

Comment: @Dan Grossman He did? I reread his post and I can *kind of* see that based on his two examples... But, I read it before it was formatted and it wasn't easy to tell that he wanted that. I don't think this warrants a downvote.

Comment: You admit that you now see that this isn't what the question asked, you have the author commenting on your answer saying it's not what he asked for, and you still think it does not warrant a downvote? This isn't a personal karma system, the votes are to identify the correct and incorrect answers to the question for the users who reads the question in the future. Those that want an answer to a way to make all values in the post array uppercase without calling strtoupper on each individual value are not served by your response, it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Dan Grossman Yes, I admit that, the OP is not fluent in English and I did not completely understand what he wanted. You can see that others made the same mistake. 

`"The upvote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. 

Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."` ~ Stack Overflow privelege page on Down Voting.

Comment: "This answer is not useful" ~ Stack Overflow alt text for the downvote button.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, this answer was useful, it helped clarify what the OP wanted :) It's no longer useful, but you can point that out and give someone a chance to edit or delete rather than going trigger crazy on the downvote button.

Comment: IMO Dan is just another of the many on SO who attempt to increase their vote count by downvoting everybody else.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? http://php.net/strtoupper